# Spherical Arrays in Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create a spherical array in blender 2.8. (I am trying to make a liposome form two opposing lipids) I understand that in the previous blender versions I would have taken my object (here the lipid) and added a sphere. Then I would have used the "dupliface" function to make the array form the faces of the sphere. In Blender 2.8, this function is gone.

Can anyone help me? I greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: could you please show a picture of your final goal?

Answer (score 3):

Try in the Object properties panel under ['Instancing'](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/index.html#instancing), that seems to work as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works